# Use IDE linter without install PHP (or Nodejs, ...) in Sublime Text, VS Code

Tags: php, docker, visual-studio-code, sublimelinter

My development use docker to build project, so I don't want to install any package  on my host machine. But when use IDE linter tool like Sublime Text or VS Code, all of linters need to specify the executable path (eg: PHP). Has anyone encountered this case yet?

Comment: You don't have to set up an environnement, I mean just download the PHP standalone (PHP 7 for VSCode) and point to it! I use vagrant and I have the PHP standalone and it works great! It's not like you have a dev environement on your machine or anything

Comment: This is what happens when you try to use a text editor as an IDE. They are different tools from one another! An IDE allows you to add remote interpreters. A text editor does not. Get a real IDE, or have fun hacking your editor with questionable plugins.